# When doing Function Pointers what is the purpose of using the address-of operator vs not using it?

Tags: c++, c

For the following code snippets why would I use one assignment vs another?  thx

```
void  addOne(int &x)
{
    x +=1;
}

void (*inc)(int &x) = addOne;   // what is the purpose of doing "addOne" 
void (*inc)(int &x) = &addOne;  //  vs &addOne ??  

int a = 10;
inc(a);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function pointers in C - address operator "unnecessary"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258422/function-pointers-in-c-address-operator-unnecessary)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of one over the other is C compatibility. C said that functions will decay to pointers-to-functions automatically. To be compatible, C++ had to do the same.

Note that when C++ introduced a new function pointer type (member function pointers), they *do not* decay automatically. So if the C++ committee had their way, odds are good you'd need that `&` there.

Answer (score 3):

Brevity, style. It's the same with using `*` when calling them.

Also note `array` vs `&array[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

From the **book C++ Programming Languauge**, it is cleary indicated that `&` and `*` operators are optional for pointers to functions:

> There are only two things one can do to a function: call it and take
>   its address. The pointer obtained by taking the address of a function
>   can then be used to call the function. For example:
>
> ```
> void error (string s) { /* ... */ }
> void (*efct )(string ); // pointer to function
> void f ()
> {
>   efct = &error ; // efct points to error
>   efct ("error "); // call error through efct
> }
> ```
>
> The compiler will discover that efct is a pointer and call the
>   function pointed to. That is, dereferencing of a pointer to function
>   using * is optional. Similarly, using & to get the address of a
>   function is optional:
>
> ```
> void (*f1 )(string ) = &error ; // ok
> void (*f2 )(string ) = error ; // also ok; same meaning as &error
> void g ()
> {
>   f1 ("Vasa"); // ok
>   (*f1 )("Mary Rose"); // also ok
> }
> ```

As others pointed out, **pointer to member function** is new/different in C++. The `&` is not optional to point a member  and it is explained as (in C++ Programming Languauge Book):

> A pointer to member can be obtained by applying the address-of
>   operator & to a fully qualified class member name, for example,
>   &Std_interface::suspend.

Answer (score -1):

A function is already a pointer; therefore, you do not need the address operator.

Comment: You do need it for member functions. Also, a function is not a pointer (but functions can decay to function pointers).

Comment: A function (name) *is* a pointer to the address, where the function code starts.

Comment: @Matthias: No. A function is a *function*. It has a type: `ReturnType(Parameters)`. Function types can *decay* to pointer-to-function types (`ReturnType(*)(Parameters)`), which as you notice is distinct from the function type. Much like arrays are not actually pointers, functions are not pointers-to-functions. One decays into the other, but that doesn't make them the same.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Sorry, but the existence of a type is not a point, each pointer has a type. One says that an array *decays*, since type information is lost (on array size). This is not the case for a function. If you want to bring it to a conceptional level, then a function declaration is a syntactical shortcat a pointer to an ananymous (lambda) function, *because* it has a type. And at implementation level, it is a pointer (address) - see the generated assembler code. You are right, if you mean the lamba part, but the OP asked for assigment of identifier, and there is a pointer at both sides.

Comment: @Matthias: `And at implementation level, it is a pointer (address)` C++ doesn't care about the *implementation*. As far as C++ is concerned, a function is a *function*. When you attempt to store it in a function *pointer*, the compiler will create a function pointer value for it. But the C++ specification doesn't say that the function value *is a pointer*. It could be whatever the compiler wants, so long as it is convertible to a function pointer. So it is most assuredly not "a pointer at both sides."

Comment: @NicolBolas: 'a function is a function' is a tautology that explains nothing. The OP's function is clearly not a member function, but an 'old' C style function. If you are trying to construct a consistent type system (okay, its rarly done for C-like languages), such a function *can't be anything else* than a pointer (or more general: a reference [*not* in C++ sense]). And the compiler 'wants' nothing, this is implementation, what (as you said) the language is not about.

Comment: @Matthias: `'a function is a function' is a tautology that explains nothing.` It explains everything. An instance of class `Object` is an `Object`. This means that it is *not* an `Object*`, or a `float`, or an `int` or anything except an `Object`. It may be implicitly convertible to all of those types (with the proper operator overloading), but that doesn't mean that they are the *same*. Just because a type that can be converted to another type doesn't mean that they are the same thing. A function is a function, not a function pointer.

Comment: An object is not a float (well, in C++), you are right. There is a difference because they *behave* different. However, a function identifier behaves always as a pointer to a function (a least, as long it is not a member). If something looks like a duck and walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck...