# unusual function pointer parameter syntax

Tags: c, syntax, function-pointers

is there any difference between this two syntaxes?

```
void fun( void (*funptr)() )
{
    funptr(); // calls the function
}

void fun( void funptr() )
{
    funptr(); // calls the function
}
```

i'd always been using the first form, but i've just seen the second one and it seems it behaves exactly the same, while the syntax is clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957742/when-doing-function-pointers-what-is-the-purpose-of-using-the-address-of-operato

Comment: AFAIK there's no difference. Unless I'm terribly mislead, functions - similarly to arrays - decay into a pointer when passed to a function. So not unlike `char arg[]` and `char *arg` being equivalent *in a function argument list* (and **only** there), I believe `func()` and `(*func)()` are equivalent in such a situation too.

Comment: @addaon No, that's not about the declaration (and the `*` *qualifier*) but the unary `*` and `&` *operators.*

Comment: Fair enough, not strictly a duplicate. The discussion in that thread about the logic behind the behavior holds pretty closely.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, fundamentally, in either form.  For both you have a function that takes a function pointer as its argument.  The function pointer must point to a function with this prototype: `void foo(void);`.

Below is an example of use:

```
void fun1(void (*funptr)(void))
{
    funptr(); // calls the function
}

void fun2(void funptr(void))
{
    funptr(); // calls the function
}

void foo(void)
{
}

int main(void)
{ 
    void (*pFun)(void) = foo;
    fun1(pFun);
    fun2(pFun);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. In both cases, `funptr` has type `void (*)()`, a function pointer type.

C99 standard, section 6.7.5.3, paragraph 8:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.