# Why can't print member function's address by it's name?

Tags: c++, class

I have learned that function name equals function address
like this:

```
void func(){}
void main() { cout << func; }
```

But when I used the same code to print memeber function, it went wrong.

```
class Test{
public:
    void func() {}
    void printFunc1() {
    cout << func << endl;
   }
    void printFunc2() {
    void (Test::*ptrtofn)() = &Test::func;
    cout << (void*&)ptrtofn << endl;
  }
};
```

`printFunction2()` work but `printFunction1()` doesnt

What makes the difference?

Member function's name is not member function's address?
Is there any reason?

Comment: "function name = function address" is not true. Instead, in some situations function can be converted to function address.

Comment: "C-style functions" ??

Comment: Non-member functions in C++ decay into a function pointer; a behaviour inherited from C. However, member functions is a C++ concept so the old cruft was dropped and you need to prefix the function name with `&` to get the pointer. Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9957957/183120).

Comment: Member function pointers are not necessarily "addresses" in the normal sense. See [this](http://ideone.com/9lYXG8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

member function != standalone function

Only standalone functions can be converted to pointer implicitely.

> **4.3 Function-to-pointer conversion [conv.func]**
>   **1** An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the function. 58
>
> 58) **This conversion never applies to non-static member functions**
>    because an lvalue that refers to a non-static member function cannot
>   be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand "func" is the member function of the class . accessing it directly is itself a compilation error .Rather you should try to use pointer to member function as you have done in printFunction2:
Else if func is function outside the class scope .Then it can be done as below :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 void func() {cout<<"\n calling func\n";}
    void printFunc1() {
       cout << endl<<hex<<(void*)func << endl;
    }
int main() {

    printFunc1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, two `endl`s in the same statement! `cout` will surely be flushed! (Don't use `std::endl` when `'\n'` will work; the latter starts a new line, and is almost always the right thing to use)