# How come the addresses of main and &main are the same?

Tags: c, memory-address

When I execute the following function, the output addresses for main and &main are the same. Is there any reason why? I don't really understand.

```
int main()
{
  printf("main=\t0x%08x\n", main);
  printf("&main=\t0x%08x\n", &main);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to do this?

Comment: When `f` is a function, both `f` and `&f` produce a pointer to the function.  It's just how the language works - basically because there's no other sensible thing either one could do, other than maybe being a syntax error.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258422/function-pointers-in-c-address-operator-unnecessary.

Comment: there is one more explanation about this [function address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552663/function-pointers-and-address-of-a-function)